# CASE WHEN column1 IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE column2 END

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I am simply fetching total number of `upvote` in `comment` table, but want the last row to print `NULL` in the `content` column.

Following is the simple query I am trying to run:

```
SELECT
    id
    , content -- THIS IS JUST TO COMPARE, WE DON'T NEED THIS
    , (CASE WHEN id IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE content END) as editedContent -- WE NEED THIS(WITH NULL VALUE IN THE END)
    , SUM(upvote)
FROM `test`.`comment`
GROUP BY id WITH ROLLUP
```

OUTPUT:

```
+------+-------------+---------------+-------------+
| id   | content     | editedContent | SUM(upvote) |
+------+-------------+---------------+-------------+
| 26   | Content13-2 | Content14-1   |           2 |
| 27   | Content14-1 | Content14-2   |           2 |
| 28   | Content14-2 | Content15-1   |           2 |
| 29   | Content15-1 | Content15-2   |           3 |
| 30   | Content15-2 | Content15-2   |           2 |
| NULL | Content15-2 | Content15-2   |          55 |
+------+-------------+---------------+-------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Expected Output:

```
+------+-------------+---------------+-------------+
| id   | content     | editedContent | SUM(upvote) |
+------+-------------+---------------+-------------+
| 26   | Content13-2 | Content13-2   |           2 |
| 27   | Content14-1 | Content14-1   |           2 |
| 28   | Content14-2 | Content14-2   |           2 |
| 29   | Content15-1 | Content15-1   |           3 |
| 30   | Content15-2 | Content15-2   |           2 |
| NULL | Content15-2 | NULL          |          55 |
+------+-------------+---------------+-------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: what is your original data?

Comment: you need structure of `comment` table ?

Comment: + data if possible, if I want to recreate your output in a fiddle

Comment: Thats the usual behaviour of `rollup` and your query with case when does not do anything to rollup, you may however use union to have the last row. Rollup will be applied on the returned data from the query so initial query with `case when` statement does not effect returned columns on rollup row.

Comment: @JeremyC. link to test.sql https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bys6bZ3t66mCc29Eb0ZfS0h0RDNfbWdFMUR5WmVVNnBZRWlj

Comment: @Jigar sent a request for access

Comment: @JeremyC. shared, and also the file is public now.

Comment: @Jigar check the answer by empiro technologies pvt. it gives you the output you wanted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following,

```
SELECT
    id
    , content -- THIS IS JUST TO COMPARE, WE DON'T NEED THIS
    , (CASE WHEN id IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE content END) as editedContent -- WE NEED THIS(WITH NULL VALUE IN THE END)
    , SUM(upvote)
FROM `test`.`comment`
GROUP BY id 

Union all

select 
    'null',
    'null',
    'null',
    SUM(upvote)
from comment
```

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
SELECT
    id
    , content -- THIS IS JUST TO COMPARE, WE DON'T NEED THIS
    , (CASE WHEN id IS NULL THEN id ELSE content END) as editedContent -- WE NEED THIS(WITH NULL VALUE IN THE END)
    , SUM(upvote)
FROM `test`.`comment`
GROUP BY id WITH ROLLUP
```